# Populate data onto UITableView with MVVM

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, mvvm

(Updated)I have this ViewModel and Viewcontroller and I have difficulties to populate the arrays of data into the tableview. 
So I have this Contact array which I created generic binding into view model. I learnt this way from internet but I failed to pull it in the ViewController.

```
class ContactViewModel: ContactViewModelProtocol {

    let contact: ContactModel
    var id: Observable<String>

    var firstName: Observable<String>

    var lastName: Observable<String>

    var email: Observable<String>

    var phone: Observable<String>

    init(_ contact: ContactModel) {
        self.contact = contact

        self.id = Observable(contact.id!)
        self.firstName = Observable(contact.firstName!)
        self.lastName = Observable(contact.lastName!)
        self.email = Observable(contact.email!)
        self.phone = Observable(contact.phone!)

    }
}

protocol ContactViewModelProtocol {
    var id: Observable<String> { get }
    var firstName: Observable<String> { get }
    var lastName: Observable<String> { get }
    var email: Observable<String> { get }
    var phone: Observable<String> { get }

}
```

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController{
 var contacts: ContactViewModel{
        didSet{
            contacts.id.bindAndFire {
                [unowned self] in
                self.textbox.text = $0
            }
            contacts.firstName.bindAndFire {
                [unowned self] in
                self.textbox.text = $0

            }
            contacts.lastName.bindAndFire {
                [unowned self] in
                self.textbox.text = $0

            }
            contacts.email.bindAndFire {
                [unowned self] in
                self.textbox.text = $0

            }
            contacts.phone.bindAndFire {
                [unowned self] in
                self.textbox.text = $0

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: This is not a code writing service, if you have tried many times then pick your best attempt and post the code.

Comment: Enough tutorials are there

Comment: hi ya, I have updated the question with more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before reading the answer below please learn this topics [Swift Codable Protocol](https://hackernoon.com/everything-about-codable-in-swift-4-97d0e18a2999) , [MVVM Design Pattern](https://benoitpasquier.com/ios-swift-mvvm-pattern/)

The way to do

```
struct TableData : Codable {
   let table : [Table]?
}
```

```
struct Table : Codable {
    let id : String?,
    let firstName : String?,
    let lastName : String?,
    let email : String?,
    let phone : String?
}
```

```
class TableViewModel {

    public var data : TableData?

    init() {

       let jsonString = """
[
  {
    "id": "1111",
    "firstName": "Phoebe",
    "lastName": "Monroe",
    "email": "phoebemonroe@furnafix.com",
    "phone": "(222) 553-3410"
  },
  {
    "id": "2222",
    "firstName": "Lidia",
    "lastName": "Wilkins",
    "email": "lidiawilkins@furnafix.com",
    "phone": "(111) 482-3866"
  }
]
"""

       let jsonData = Data(jsonString.utf8)
       data = try decoder.decode(TableData.self, from: jsonData)
    }

}

class TableViewController : UITableViewController , UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet lazy weak var tableView : UITableView!

    var viewModel : TableViewModel?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self 
        tableView.dataSource = self
        viewModel = TableViewModel()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.table.count
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. May I know implement tableview into ViewModel is correct MVVM way?

Comment: follow tutorials , there are many tutorials here for this , like one https://benoitpasquier.com/ios-swift-mvvm-pattern/

Comment: hi ya, I have updated the question with more details